# Wheel stuck to Rotor

Tags: brakes, dodge, brake-rotor, durango

My 2000 Durango 2 wheel drive front tire is seized to the rotor, I tried the heating method and hitting but still seized, how can I get it off without damaging the wheel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wheel stuck or fused to drum](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/881/wheel-stuck-or-fused-to-drum)

Comment: I think this a bit different and not a dupe.

Comment: The *tire* seized to the rotor? Damn, what happened?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to take care of this which I've found is to:

- Jack up and secure the vehicle (or wheel)
- Take all lug nuts off
- Sit on your butt in front of the offending wheel
- With your feet, pound alternately from one side to the other until the wheel comes loose

This is a process, which can take some time. I've found this works the fastest in getting a wheel free. You can also use a heavy hammer, ensuring you are only hitting rubber.

Answer (score 2):

All I can suggest it to soak the rim with a [quality Rust Penetrate](http://wd40specialist.com/products/penetrating-oil), squirt it into the lug nut holes with the lug nuts removed, do this several times a day over a few days, rotate the wheel 180 degrees each time right before you soak it, let the penetrate do the work.

Once it has soaked a couple of days, get someone with a big foot and large leg to kick the side of the tire near the edge to break it loose from the rotor. If there is a safe place to use a long pry bar on the wheel you can get some leverage that way.

You can also use a length of 2x6 lumber, rest it against the side of the tire near the outer edge and have someone swing a 15lb sledge hammer hitting the board hard. Use a long board (6ft or longer) so the one holding it is clear of the swinging hammer.

Answer (score 2):

This is my method of last resort when lube, heat, brute force failed. Loosen all the lug nuts 2-3 turns, alternate between forward and reverse while accelerating 2 or 3 feet in each direction. Hit the brakes hard between each direction change. Have an observer watch for the wheel to move. Jack up the vehicle remove the lug nuts and try the methods that didn't work the first time. For safety sake I leave one lug nut on but very loose. That way the wheel can't fly off and roll down the driveway, etc.

Comment: Hard turns will help also.